# Error:Failed to find target with hash string 'android-24' in:

Tags: android

are you good.
I was inexperienced, very much like android, but encountered difficulties when creating the project .
I used to compile tools are android studio 2.2 Preview5.
After creating the project, find errors.

```
Error:Failed to find target with hash string 'android-24' in: E:\android-sdk-windows
<a href="install.android.platform">Install missing platform(s) and sync                project</a>
```

### buid.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "www.jike.com.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.0', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha4'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Because it is self-learning , so no one can consult。
 In stackoverflow, I found a similar problem,But I don't know much about。

I am a novice don't understand,Hope friends detailed explanation,  thank you very much.

My English is not good , the above words are translated using the software , the term is not accurate enough , please forgive me.

I hope to get help. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

> Error:Failed to find target with hash string 'android-24'

***Open SDK Manager and check Update***

You can use

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"
```

And set

1. **targetSdkVersion 23**
2. **compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'**

Finally , `Clean-Rebuild` and *Run*.

Comment: Thank you very much , but because of the network 's SDK update failed , what other ways?

Answer (score -3):

yur problem is download gradle with correct

[image]